# Ingesting 150 csv's into one data source

Tags: python, elasticsearch, bigdata

Hello i am completely new to handling big data and comfortable in python
I have 150 csv's each of size 70MB which i have to integrate in one source to remove basic stats  like unique counts, unique names and all.

Any one could suggest how should i go about it? 
I came across a package  'pyelastic   search' in python how feasible it is  for me to use in enthaught canopy.

Suggestion needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `pandas` package.

reading a single csv would be:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filelocation.csv')
```

in case of multiple files, just `concat` them. let's say `ls` is a list of file locations, then:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in ls])
```

and then to write them as a single file, do:

```
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

of course all this is valid for in-memory operations (70x150 = ~ 10.5 GB RAM). If that's not possible - consider building an incremental process or using `dask` dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

One option if you are in AWS

Step1 - move data to S3 (AWS native File storage)
Step2 - create table for each data structure in redshift
Step3 - run COPY command to move data from S3 to Redshift (AWS native DW)

```
    COPY command loads data in bulk, detects file name pattern
```